# work with form in mvc and error null exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

pls help me . i write this Razor Code :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("send", "default", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit 1" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit 2" />
}
```

Controler Code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public HtmlString send(FormCollection frm)
    {
        string _data = frm["txtNumber"];
        //
        // HOW ? if submit 1 clicked       _data + "x" = result
        //
        // HOW ? if submit 2 clicked       _data + "y" = result
        //
        return new HtmlString(_data);

    }
```

but this Error :( 
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    > **string _data = frm["txtNumber"];** . Tnqs pls help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("send", "default", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" id="txtNumber" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="btn1">submit 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn" value="btn2">submit 2</button>
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public HtmlString send(FormCollection frm)
{
    string _data = frm["txtNumber"];

    string btn = frm["btn"];
    if (btn == "btn1")
    {
        // submit 1 was clicked
    }
    else 
    {
        // submit 2 was clicked
    }

    return new HtmlString(_data);
}
```